# Form key or value length limit 2048 exceeded

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core to build API. I have a request that allow user to upload profile image using this code

```
 [HttpPost("{company_id}/updateLogo")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> updateCompanyLogo(IFormFile imgfile,int company_id)
        {
            string imageName;
            // upload file
            if (imgfile == null || imgfile.Length == 0)
                imageName = "default-logo.jpg";
            else
            {
                imageName = Guid.NewGuid() + imgfile.FileName;
                var path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $@"\Imgs\{imageName}";
                if (imgfile.ContentType.ToLower().Contains("image"))
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await imgfile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }
.
.
```

but it keeps returning this exception: `Form key or value length limit 2048 exceeded`
**The Request** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvFNy.png

**Update:**
I have tried this code but it doesn't work

```
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; //not recommended value
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; //not recommended value
    });
```

Comment: It `services.Configure<FormOptions>` works in .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: Try this solution it works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71085281/14550822

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Core enforces key/value length limit of 2048 inside [`FormReader`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/FormReader.cs/) as constant and applied in [`FormOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/FormOptions.cs) as shown below:

```
public class FormReader : IDisposable
{
    public const int DefaultValueCountLimit = 1024;
    public const int DefaultKeyLengthLimit = 1024 * 2; // 2048
    public const int DefaultValueLengthLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 4; // 4194304
    // other stuff
}

public class FormOptions
{
    // other stuff
    public int ValueCountLimit { get; set; } = DefaultValueCountLimit;
    public int KeyLengthLimit { get; set; } = FormReader.DefaultKeyLengthLimit;
    public int ValueLengthLimit { get; set; } = DefaultValueLengthLimit;
    // other stuff
}
```

Hence, you may create a custom attribute to explicitly set key/value length limit on your own by using `KeyValueLimit` and `ValueCountLimit` property (also `ValueLengthLimit` etc.):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RequestSizeLimitAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    private readonly FormOptions _formOptions;

    public RequestSizeLimitAttribute(int valueCountLimit)
    {
        _formOptions = new FormOptions()
        {
            // tip: you can use different arguments to set each properties instead of single argument
            KeyLengthLimit = valueCountLimit,
            ValueCountLimit = valueCountLimit,
            ValueLengthLimit = valueCountLimit

            // uncomment this line below if you want to set multipart body limit too
            // MultipartBodyLengthLimit = valueCountLimit
        };
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    // taken from /a/38396065
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var contextFeatures = context.HttpContext.Features;
        var formFeature = contextFeatures.Get<IFormFeature>();

        if (formFeature == null || formFeature.Form == null)
        {
            // Setting length limit when the form request is not yet being read
            contextFeatures.Set<IFormFeature>(new FormFeature(context.HttpContext.Request, _formOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example in action method:

```
[HttpPost("{company_id}/updateLogo")]
[RequestSizeLimit(valueCountLimit: 2147483648)] // e.g. 2 GB request limit
public async Task<IActionResult> updateCompanyLogo(IFormFile imgfile, int company_id)
{
    // contents removed for brevity
}
```

**NB:** If latest version of ASP.NET Core is being used, change property named `ValueCountLimit` to `KeyCountLimit`.

**Update:** The `Order` property must be included on attribute class because it is a member of implemented interface `IOrderedFilter`.

Similar issues:

[Form submit resulting in "InvalidDataException: Form value count limit 1024 exceeded."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357108/form-submit-resulting-in-invaliddataexception-form-value-count-limit-1024-exce)

[Request.Form throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394410/request-form-throws-exception)

Comment: I added update for interface member `IOrderedFilter`, can you confirm which `features` name giving CS0103 error?

Comment: It appears to just take a long, without any fieldname: - and neither of the fieldnames work for me.

Which is just as well, because I still get the exception about it apparently limiting the file size to 2K when we try to upload?  (Who came up with that crazy limit??)

Comment: Thanks,  [RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue)] did it for me for .net core 3.1

Answer (score 9):

For my case adding the `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` attribute  solved error; this can be helpful when you are not sure about the maximum length of request. This is formal [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.disablerequestsizelimitattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

```
    [HttpPost("bulk")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Entry>), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BulkCreateEntry([FromBody] IEnumerable<CreateStockEntryFromCommand> command)
    {
        // do your work
    }
```

Comment: Easy and effective. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

This answer was really helpful, thanks.
But since .Net Core 2.1 there are built-in attributes for this purpose, e.g. [RequestFormLimitsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestformlimitsattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or [RequestSizeLimitAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestsizelimitattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
 {
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
 });
```

it solved my problem

Comment: I also added `options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;` to this list +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm on .Net6 and this is all I needed. (In my startup file inside `ConfigureServices(services)`.)

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```