# ASP.NET Core 2 - Missing content-type boundary

Tags: c#, angular, http, asp.net-core-2.0, content-type

I'm trying to upload a file from a Angular client to my ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI service. When I call the service, I get back an Internal Server Error. That's the error I'm getting:
[image]

The component I'm using client-side is this one: [ngx-uploader](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader)

In my request options, i set them as you can see here:

```
  const event: UploadInput = {
  type: 'uploadAll',
  url: this.printService.apiFilesBaseUrl + '/Upload',
  method: 'POST',
  file: this.files[0],
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken()
  }
};
```

While, server-side my controller action signature is this one:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    [Authorize]
    public Guid Post(IFormFile file)
```

Breakpoints in this controller action never get hit.

Can someone please share ideas about what's happening here?

Here, as requested, i will post my request header and payload:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try 'uploadFile' instead of  'uploadAll' in the UploadInput

Comment: @PraveenRai nothing changes.

Comment: Share us the request header and body from network tab in web browser.

Comment: Edited the question, please check it out

Comment: @mororo Did you happen to get any solution to this issue? I am facing the same issue right now. I have some input fields along with a file. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @PrasadKaiche The verified solution you can find on this thread helped me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check upload request in developer tools network tab, it should have correct format (matching `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`), also you could try removing this header.

Comment: The header is in correct format "multipart/form-data", i just checked in the network tab.

Comment: Check the body of request, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request

Comment: Check it to find out what? Can you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: the body of request, its structure must match declared header

Comment: They do not match. My header has, as content type, "multipart/form-data" meanwhile the request payload has "application/json". That's strange, i did setup the component options to send a post request with content type "multipart/form-data" as you can see above. It maybe a problem with the component i'm using?

Comment: I did add to the question my header and payload so you can check it out

Comment: Try to remove `Content-Type` from your config, probably it is set automatically by uploader. https://ngx-uploader.com/ is working example.

Comment: You got it right! Thank you! Everything is now working fine

Comment: Thanks @kemsky. Yes, `Content-Type` will vary depending on the file type you are uploading. Removing a configuration of it made it working!

Comment: You made my day on Android development using Retrofit2 ! Thank you ! @kemsky

Comment: strange, but completely removed Content-Type and it works!!

Answer (score 7):

You can add **content-type:** as **multipart/form-data; boundary=--14737809831466499882746641449**.

I am testing API on postman and added content-type like above it worked for me.

Comment: When using `curl`, I was sending just `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` without an issue, but on postman I had to add that boundary part too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having similar problem in netcore 3.1 or net 6.0, please make sure You have the **Consumes** attribute, i.e.:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportItems(IFormFile file)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Angular 14, if you set the header like this:

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
};
```

then you should remove this header so Web Browser will add this `Content-Type` header itself, i.e:

> multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAGc4qL8mDa483NA2

Also make sure that you add `enctype` attribute of html form element with value `multipart/form-data`, i.e:

```
<form #htmlForm method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" (submit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
```

and decorate your asp.net core web api action with `Consumes` attribute, i.e:

```
[HttpPost("version")]                                     
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]          
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAppVersion()
{
```