# Receiving Multi-part form data in dotnet core web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I'm working on an web API, where it needs to receive the multi-part form data with in a model. As of now it's not receiving the request and showing the Bad request When I tried from the Postman.
My model :

```
public class InvoiceDetails
    {

  
        public int? po_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string grn_status { get; set; }
        public int utilization_amount { get; set; }
        public int currency_id { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
        public string currency_symbol { get; set; }

        [FromForm(Name = "invoice_file")]
        public List<IFormCollection> invoice_file { get;set;}
        [FromForm(Name = "other_files")]
        public List<IFormCollection> other_files { get; set; }
        
        
    }
```

In the above class/model "invoice_file" and "other_files" can have multiple file uploads so I made it List.

My Action Method :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateInvoice")]
        public IActionResult CreateInvoice([FromForm]InvoiceDetails idobj )
        {
            //var modelData = Request.Form["invoice_file"];
           
            Response resobj = new Response();
            try
            {
                if (idobj.invoice_file.Count > 0)
                {
                   
                    resobj = _dataContext.AddInvoice(idobj);
                    if (resobj.flag == true)
                    {
                        Upload(idobj);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    resobj.flag = false;
                    resobj.message = "please upload atleast one invioce file";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              
            }
        
            return Ok(resobj);
    }
```

How can I make the action method or model, in such a way that user can upload the model with multiple files to the properties other_files & invoice_file.

Reference of postman Image [image: Postman reference Image]

Comment: Do you mean `List<IFormFile>`? Also, show your Postman request.

Comment: @CodeCaster ,  Yes, But it should receive multiple files. Please check my reference post man image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943586/asp-net-core-2-missing-content-type-boundary

Comment: @CodeCaster In the link you given, He can only post the file(one argument). But here I'm expecting the Objecct which may contain the files too. How can I design my API or action method in such a way..

Comment: By using `List<IFormFile>` and setting the appropriate request headers. Don't dismiss a relevant link because there are differences, look at the similarities, in this case the error message.

Comment: List<IFormFile> will capture only files. But how do I can retrieve other information which exists in my model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `CodeCaster` says,add `Content-Type:multipart/form-data;` and change `List<IFormCollection>` to `List<IFormFile>`.It is not changing the whole model to List.So you can also  retrieve other information which exists in your model with idobj.xxx.Change

```
public class InvoiceDetails
    {

  
        public int? po_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string grn_status { get; set; }
        public int utilization_amount { get; set; }
        public int currency_id { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
        public string currency_symbol { get; set; }

        [FromForm(Name = "invoice_file")]
        public List<IFormCollection> invoice_file { get;set;}
        [FromForm(Name = "other_files")]
        public List<IFormCollection> other_files { get; set; }
        
        
    }
```

to

```
public class InvoiceDetails
    {


        public int? po_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string grn_status { get; set; }
        public int utilization_amount { get; set; }
        public int currency_id { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
        public string currency_symbol { get; set; }

        [FromForm(Name = "invoice_file")]
        public List<IFormFile> invoice_file { get; set; }
        [FromForm(Name = "other_files")]
        public List<IFormFile> other_files { get; set; }


    }
```

result:
[image]
IFormCollection is used to retrieve all the values from posted form data.refer to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

If you want to use c,you can try to use it,you can do like this

```
public IActionResult CreateInvoice([FromForm]IFormCollection idobj)
```

and you need to get the data you want to foreach keys of IFormCollection,so `public List<IFormCollection> invoice_file { get;set;}` is better than use IFormCollection.