# Javascript Pass new Formdata to dotnet API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core

For some reason, I have to new FormData() in the view and pass to API
In view, the javascript like this:

```
pushButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "SessionData")';
  var formData = new FormData();                    
  formData.append('DateFrom', '2022-7-1');
  formData.append('DateTo', '2022-7-5');
  formData.append('ItemCode', 'AK911');
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      success: function (result, status, xhr) { dosomething}
   });
```

In the backend, SessionDataContoller, I have create the httpPost record

```
[HttpPost("GetData")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromForm] FormQuery query)
{
    return ProcessByteResponse(await webService.GetQueryData(query));
}
```

When I run it, it always return :

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-da6621225f50794e9130b4a212996da2-6e46d4edf1f67e43-00","errors":{"":["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]}}
```

Can I know any idea? as  I need to bind the form to view , but I cannot use form tag in html body

Comment: You can refer to this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943586/asp-net-core-2-missing-content-type-boundary).

Answer (score 0):

Your `content-type` header is missing the mandatory `boundary` parameter, which you can't predict.

Tell jQuery not to set a `content-type`. Allow the underlying browser APIs to generate it from the FormData object.

```
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
```