# Can a Form POST be too large for MVC Model Binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-binding

This problem occurs in .net core 3.1 MVC website.

I am having trouble getting my POST to bind to my controller action (the parameter always comes through as null). The data is loaded from a database, and is a large recursive structure.
If I delete a few hundred lines of the JSON (out of 2500 or so) in the database it will bind OK.

The GET displays perfectly.

Even when I change my Action method parameter from my ViewModel to IFormCollection, it still comes through as null. Is there some limit here that I wasn't aware of?
If the size is the issue, is there a better approach for POSTing the data?

**Parent View**

```
<form id="frmAdditionalCodes" name="frmAdditionalCodes" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td style="width:50px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Code)
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Code" class="form-control" style="display:none" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:50px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.FullName)
                    <input asp-for="@Model.FullName" class="form-control" style="display:none" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:50px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Description)
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control" style="display:none" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:20px">
                    <span>
                        <i id="addTagItem" class="fas fa-folder-plus" title="Add child item"></i>
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <partial name="~/Views/PartialViews/_SectionsAndTags.cshtml" model="@Model.Entities" view-data="ViewData" />
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Child View**

```
<table class="partial_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Entities)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ List<CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagItemViewModel> list = Model.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
            {
                    <tr>
                        @{
                            string elementNameCode = $"{list[i].Prefix}Code";
                            string elementNameFullName = $"{list[i].Prefix}FullName";
                            string elementNameDescription = $"{list[i].Prefix}Description";
                            string elementNameIsDeleted = $"{list[i].Prefix}IsDeleted";
                        }
                        <td>
                            <span>@list[i].Code</span>
                            <input asp-for="@list[i].Code" name="@elementNameCode" class="form-control" style="display: none" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>@list[i].FullName</span>
                            <input asp-for="@list[i].FullName" class="form-control" name="@elementNameFullName" style="display: none" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>@list[i].Description</span>
                            <input asp-for="@list[i].Description" class="form-control" name="@elementNameDescription" style="display: none" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (list[i].Entities?.Length > 0)
                            {<img id="collapseItem" state="expanded" width="20" height="20" src="~/images/minus_PNG24.png" />
                            }

                            <span>
                                <i id="editTagItem" class="fas fa-pencil-alt" title="Edit item"></i>
                                <i id="deleteTagItem" class="far fa-trash-alt" title="Delete item"></i>
                                <i id="addTagItem" class="fas fa-folder-plus" title="Add child item"></i>
                                <i id="updateTagItem" class="far fa-save" title="Save changes" style="display: none"></i>
                                <i id="cancelTagItem" class="fas fa-undo-alt" title="Undo changes" style="display: none"></i>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (list[i].Entities?.Length > 0)
                            {
                                <partial name="~/Views/PartialViews/_SectionsAndTags.cshtml" model="@list[i].Entities" />
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" value="false" name="@elementNameIsDeleted" />

                        </td>

                    </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagViewModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagItemViewModel[] Entities { get; set; }
}

public class CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagItemViewModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagItemViewModel[] Entities { get; set; }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**
Here vm is null unless I remove some data

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CdsDeclarationSectionAndTag(CdsDeclarationSectionAndTagViewModel vm)
        {
        }
```

If I change it like so, fc is also null

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CdsDeclarationSectionAndTag(IFormCollection fc)
        {
        }
```

The posted Form Data looks like this (and can end up with 4 or 5 recursive levels)

> Code: 42A
> FullName:
> Description: Declaration
> Entities[0].Code: 023
> Entities[0].FullName: Acceptance (taxpoint) datetime
> Entities[0].Description: Acceptance (taxpoint)  datetime
> Entities[0].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[1].Code: D026
> Entities[1].FullName: LRN
> Entities[1].Description: LRN
> Entities[1].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[2].Code: D013
> Entities[2].FullName: Declaration type
> Entities[2].Description: Declaration type
> Entities[2].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[3].Code: 109
> Entities[3].FullName: Invoice total
> Entities[3].Description: Invoice total
> Entities[3].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[4].Code: 504
> Entities[4].FullName: Specific circumstances indicator
> Entities[4].Description: Specific circumstances indicator
> Entities[4].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[5].Code: 131
> Entities[5].FullName: Gross mass
> Entities[5].Description: Gross mass
> Entities[5].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[6].Code: 146
> Entities[6].FullName: Total packages
> Entities[6].Description: Total packages
> Entities[6].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[7].Code: 61B
> Entities[7].FullName: Authentication
> Entities[7].Description: Authentication
> Entities[7].Entities[0].Code: 104
> Entities[7].Entities[0].FullName: Signature/Authentication
> Entities[7].Entities[0].Description: Signature/Authentication
> Entities[7].Entities[0].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[7].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[8].Code: 02A
> Entities[8].FullName: Deferred Payment
> Entities[8].Description: Deferred Payment
> Entities[8].Entities[0].Code: D031
> Entities[8].Entities[0].FullName: Deferment category code
> Entities[8].Entities[0].Description: Category code
> Entities[8].Entities[0].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[8].Entities[1].Code: D005
> Entities[8].Entities[1].FullName: Deferment ID
> Entities[8].Entities[1].Description: ID
> Entities[8].Entities[1].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[8].Entities[2].Code: D006
> Entities[8].Entities[2].FullName: Deferment Type
> Entities[8].Entities[2].Description: Type
> Entities[8].Entities[2].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[8].IsDeleted: false
> Entities[9].Code: 03A
> Entities[9].FullName: Additional Information
> Entities[9].Description: Additional Information
> Entities[9].Entities[0].Code: 226
> Entities[9].Entities[0].FullName: Additional Information Statement code
> Entities[9].Entities[0].Description: Statement code
> Entities[9].Entities[0].IsDeleted: false
> ....

Comment: Try adding [DisableRequestSizeLimit] attribute at action CdsDeclarationSectionAndTag, my friend.

Comment: I tried this actually, and still encountered the same error, but it's a good suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357108/form-submit-resulting-in-invaliddataexception-form-value-count-limit-1024-exce) thread.
It turns out that by default, there is a limit of 1024 on Form Values that you can submit.

I used the following code in Startup.cs to change the limit and the problem has gone away, and can now bind successfully

```
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });
```

Comment: Well played, my friend :d