# (.net core MVC) Model is being returned null after form post but only when deployed to on premise IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am having this extremely bizarre issue where the my model is coming back as null after submitting my form.

Now I understand that a model coming back null is not necessarily bizarre on its own, but what makes it extremely bizarre is that it only happens on very specific conditions:

- When the application has been deployed to my on-premise IIS server
- When I have first modified the date filters for my data

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening since when I run on local, everything works fine. But once I deploy on the on-prem server, and I modify my date filters for the page I start getting this error.

Here is my view:

```
@model CoFCrimeBulletin.Models.ViewModels.CallsForServiceViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calls For Service";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div style="margin-left: 400px; width: 100%">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Arrests">Arrests</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Warrants">Warrants</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="StreetChecks">Street Checks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark active" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CallsForService">Calls For Service</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container pt-5 CallsForService" >
    
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CallsForService" method="post">
        <div class=row>

            <div class="pr-2">
                <label><b>Search: </b></label>
                <input type="text" id="WarrantsSearch" onkeyup="myWarrantsFunction()" placeholder="Search Calls for Service">
            </div>

            <div class="pr-2">
                <label><b>Start Date: </b></label>
                <input id="CallsForServiceStartDate" type="date" asp-for="@Model.StartDate" class="text-box single-line" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
            </div>
            <div class="pr-2">
                <label><b>End Date: </b></label>
                <input id="CallsForServiceEndDate" type="date" asp-for="@Model.EndDate" class="text-box single-line" value="@Model.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="VerifyDates()">Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-4 tableheading"><b>LOCAL CRIME</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row details">
        <div class="col-sm" style="text-align:center"><b>Details</b></div>
    </div>
     <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreatePDF" method="post">
    <div id="LocalCrimeTable">
       
        @{
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.callsForService.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="row suspectName">
                    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                        <b>@Model.callsForService[i].type - @Model.callsForService[i].location</b> 
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].location" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].location">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].type" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].type">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:right"> 
                        <b>@Model.callsForService[i].datetime</b>
                        <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].datetime" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row rmsNumber">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <b>@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnumdisplay</b>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnumdisplay" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnumdisplay">
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnum" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnum">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <b>@Model.callsForService[i].zone</b>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].zone" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].zone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <b>COMPLAINTANT:</b> @Model.callsForService[i].caller
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].caller" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].caller">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm"> 
                        <b>REMARKS:</b> @Model.callsForService[i].remarks
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].remarks" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].remarks">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm"> 
                        <b>CLEAR REMARKS:</b> @Model.callsForService[i].clearremarks
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].clearremarks" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].clearremarks">
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                if(Model.IsWriter)
                {
                    <div  id="td">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary additionalInfoEdit" data-target="#additionalInfoModal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="additionalInfoRender('@Model.callsForService[i].rmsnum', '@ViewData["Title"]', '@Model.StartDate.ToString()', '@Model.EndDate.ToString()')">+</a>
                    </div>
                }


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"> <b>ADDITIONAL NOTES:</b> 
                        @if(Model.callsForService[i].additionalnotes != null && Model.callsForService[i].additionalnotes != ""){
                            <p class="truncateCrime">@Model.callsForService[i].additionalnotes</p>
                            <a  class="expandNotesCrime underline text-green-500 button" href="#">Read more...</a>
                            <a  class="shrinkNotesCrime underline text-green-500 button" href="#" style="display:none">Read less...</a>
                        }
                        <input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].additionalnotes" style="display:none;" value="@Model.callsForService[i].additionalnotes">

                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="row" style="text-transform:capitalize">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input asp-for="@Model.callsForService[i].createPDF" type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;  Check to Include in PDF
                </div>
            }

            <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.StartDate" style="display:none;" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">
            <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.EndDate" style="display:none;" value="@Model.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">
            <input asp-for="@Model.SourcePage" style="display:none;" value="@Model.SourcePage">
        }
    </div>
        @{
    
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" value="Create PDF">
        }
        </form>
    </div>
```

And my Controller:

```
using CoFCrimeBulletin.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace CoFCrimeBulletin.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        public IConfiguration _configuration;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        private bool IsWriter()
        {
            bool localtest = false;
            if (localtest) { return true; }
            else
            {
                //ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
                var UI = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
                List<string> Groups = new List<string>();
                if (UI.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var group in UI.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups"))
                    {
                        Groups.Add(group.Value);
                    }
                }

                return Groups.Contains("f615ae09-b313-444a-a41c-5dc2d586fc03");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Index(Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel model)
        {
            Models.ViewModels.HomePageViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.HomePageViewModel();
            Repository.WarrantRepository warrantRepository = new Repository.WarrantRepository(_configuration);
            Repository.ArrestRepository arrestRepository = new Repository.ArrestRepository(_configuration);
            Repository.CrimeRepository crimeRepository = new Repository.CrimeRepository(_configuration);

            DateTime startDate = model.StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = model.EndDate;

            myModel.warrants = warrantRepository.GetWarrants(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.arrests = arrestRepository.GetArrests(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.streetChecks = crimeRepository.GetStreetChecks(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.callsForService = crimeRepository.GetCallsForService(startDate, endDate);

            myModel.StartDate = startDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) : startDate;
            myModel.EndDate = endDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : endDate;
            myModel.IsWriter = IsWriter();
            myModel.SourcePage = "Index";

            return View(myModel);
        }


        public IActionResult Warrants(Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startDate = model.StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = model.EndDate;
            Models.ViewModels.WarrantViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.WarrantViewModel();
            myModel.StartDate = startDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) : startDate;
            myModel.EndDate = endDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : endDate;
            Repository.WarrantRepository warrantRepository = new Repository.WarrantRepository(_configuration);
            myModel.Warrants = warrantRepository.GetWarrants(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.IsWriter = IsWriter();
            myModel.SourcePage = "Warrants";


            return View(myModel);
        }


        public IActionResult Arrests(Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startDate = model.StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = model.EndDate;
            Models.ViewModels.ArrestViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.ArrestViewModel();
            myModel.StartDate = startDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) : startDate;
            myModel.EndDate = endDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : endDate;
            Repository.ArrestRepository arrestRepository = new Repository.ArrestRepository(_configuration);
            myModel.arrests = arrestRepository.GetArrests(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.IsWriter = IsWriter();
            myModel.SourcePage = "Arrests";

            return View(myModel);
        }


        public IActionResult StreetChecks(Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startDate = model.StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = model.EndDate;
            Models.ViewModels.StreetChecksViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.StreetChecksViewModel();
            myModel.StartDate = startDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) : startDate;
            myModel.EndDate = endDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : endDate;
            Repository.CrimeRepository crimeRepository = new Repository.CrimeRepository(_configuration);
            myModel.streetChecks = crimeRepository.GetStreetChecks(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.IsWriter = IsWriter();
            myModel.SourcePage = "StreetChecks";

            return View(myModel);
        }


        public IActionResult CallsForService(Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startDate = model.StartDate;
            DateTime endDate = model.EndDate;
            Models.ViewModels.CallsForServiceViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.CallsForServiceViewModel();

            myModel.StartDate = startDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) : startDate;
            myModel.EndDate = endDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : endDate;

            Repository.CrimeRepository crimeRepository = new Repository.CrimeRepository(_configuration);

            myModel.callsForService = crimeRepository.GetCallsForService(startDate, endDate);
            myModel.IsWriter = IsWriter();
            myModel.SourcePage = "CallsForService";

            return View(myModel);
        }


        public IActionResult AddAdditionalNote(Models.ViewModels.AdditionalInfoViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                Repository.AdditionalNotesRepository additionalNotesRepository = new Repository.AdditionalNotesRepository(_configuration);

                string redirectAction = Helpers.AdditionalInfoHelper.GetRedirectActionName(model.sourcePage);

                Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel();

                string rmsNum = model.rmsNum.Replace("-", string.Empty);
                string remarks = model.additionalNotes == null? "" : model.additionalNotes;
                myModel.StartDate = model.StartDate;
                myModel.EndDate = model.EndDate;
                additionalNotesRepository.InsertAdditionalNotes(rmsNum, remarks);

                return RedirectToAction(redirectAction, myModel);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]);
        }


        public PartialViewResult RenderAdditionalInfoModal(string RmsNum, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, string SourcePage)
        {
            string rms = RmsNum.Replace("-", string.Empty);
            Repository.AdditionalNotesRepository additionalNotesRepository = new Repository.AdditionalNotesRepository(_configuration);
            Models.ViewModels.AdditionalInfoViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.AdditionalInfoViewModel();
            myModel.rmsNum = RmsNum;
            myModel.StartDate = StartDate;
            myModel.EndDate = EndDate;
            myModel.sourcePage = SourcePage;
            
            myModel.additionalNotes = additionalNotesRepository.GetAdditionalNote(rms);

            return PartialView("_AdditionalInfoPartial", myModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreatePDF(Models.ViewModels.HomePageViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {

                Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel myModel = new Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel();
                Models.PdfCreation pdf = new Models.PdfCreation();
                string redirectAction = model.SourcePage;

                redirectAction = Helpers.AdditionalInfoHelper.GetRedirectActionName(model.SourcePage);

                myModel.StartDate = model.StartDate;
                myModel.EndDate = model.EndDate;
                pdf.arrests = Helpers.PdfHelper.GetArrestsForPdfCreation(model.arrests);
                pdf.warrants = Helpers.PdfHelper.GetWarrantsForPdfCreation(model.warrants);
                pdf.callsForService = Helpers.PdfHelper.GetCallsForServiceForPdfCreation(model.callsForService);
                pdf.streetChecks = Helpers.PdfHelper.GetStreetChecksForPdfCreation(model.streetChecks);

                Helpers.PdfHelper.CreatePdf(pdf);

                return RedirectToAction(redirectAction, myModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CrimeBulletin PDFs\out.txt", true))
                {
                    Console.SetOut(writer);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
                return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"]);
            }

        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }


        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoFCrimeBulletin.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public List<Arrest> arrests { get; set; }
        public List<Warrant> warrants { get; set; }
        public List<Crime> callsForService { get; set; }
        public List<Crime> streetChecks { get; set; }

        public HomePageViewModel()
        {
            arrests = new List<Arrest>();
            warrants = new List<Warrant>();
            callsForService = new List<Crime>();
            streetChecks = new List<Crime>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CoFCrimeBulletin.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class CallsForServiceViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public List<Crime> callsForService { get; set; }

        public CallsForServiceViewModel()
        {
            callsForService = new List<Crime>();
        }
    }
}
```

And a screen shot showing the model is null when I submit the form:

[Null model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxbYb.png)

And a screen shot showing that the model is in fact populating if I don't modify the date filters:

[Populated model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6k26.png)

Its important to note that both these screenshots are showing the results of the same form being submitted. Also want to point out that these screen shots are taken from remote debug on the server. Not from my local machine.

Also important to note that when I run this on my local machine, I can submit any way I want including after modifying the date filters and I never get a null model back. I have only been able to replicate this error when the app is deployed to my on-prem IIS server.

I have not been able to find any other posts that match the issues I am having. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Since I am posting back all of the data shown on screen to my controller then sorting from there, could the issue be that the model is null when too much data is being posted to the controller model? Currently looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found and resolved the issue. It had nothing to do with being deployed to the on-premise IIS server or the fact that I was changing the date range and everything to do with the size of the dataset that I was posting back to the controller.

Since I am posting back all of my data back to my controller then sorting based the checkbox value, the amount of data sent back to my controller was exceeding the default limits set by asp.net core MVC.

Now as one might guess ,I was working with a small enough dataset on my local as to not exceed the limit. Furthermore, increasing the date-range of my filter would have the secondary effect of making the dataset larger.

SOLUTION:

The reason I had so much trouble identifying this error is because I was only getting nullReference errors and wasn't getting "InvalidDataException: Form value count limit 1024 exceeded."

Which, once I identified the issue brought me to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357108/form-submit-resulting-in-invaliddataexception-form-value-count-limit-1024-exce) which informed me you can override the default limit with this bit of code:

```
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    });
```

in the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

I added that bit of code and the isssue went away. The model is now properly binding with large sets of data.